# Scala: filtering a collection of Options

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter, scala-option

Say I have a function that checks whether some operation is applicable to an instance of A and, if so, returns an instance of B or None:

```
   def checker[A,B]( a: A ) : Option[B] = ...
```

Now I want to form a new collection that contains all valid instances of B, dropping the None values. The following code seems to do the job, but there is certainly a better way:

```
   val as = List[A]( a1, a2, a3, ... )
   val bs = 
     as
     .map( (a) => checker(a) )    // List[A] => List[Option[B]]
     .filter( _.isDefined )       // List[Option[B]] => List[Option[B]]
     .map( _.get )                // List[Option[B]] => List[B]
```

Comment: flatMap that shit

Comment: @oxbow_lakes I believe the correct quote is: _"What's this? Amateur hour? flatMap that shit!"_

Comment: Did that quote originate on twitter?

Comment: Where is that quote from? who made it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should do it:

```
val bs = as.flatMap(checker)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me for various reasons: 1. type inference, 2. List#flatMap expects a GenTraversableOnce. The correct is as.flatMap{a => checker[A, B](a)}

Comment: I tested it with a function from `Int` to `Option[String]`. Worst case, you have to add some explicit types to it.

Answer (score 11):

The answer above is correct, but if you can rewrite `checker`, I suggest you use `PartialFunction` and `collect`. PartialFunction is a function of type A=>B that is not necessary defined for all values of A. Here is a simple example:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4, "5") collect {case x : Int => x + 42}
res1: List[Int] = List(43, 44, 45, 46)
```

`collect` takes an instance of PartialFunction as argument and applies it to all elements of the collection. In our case the function is defined only for `Ints` and `"5"` is filtered. So, `collect` is a combination of `map` and `filter`, which is exactly your case.

Comment: `collect` is indeed a combination of `filter` and then `map`, but it doesn't generally work in the other direction (`map` **then** `filter`), since you need to define the filter in the guard of the case statement.  So it'd be great for replacing the OP's last two statements (with `.collect { case Some(x) => x }`), but if `checker` involves any sort of non-trivial calculation to decide whether to return a `Some` or a `None`, this might be difficult to write as a partial function.